# My MBP won’t start up and I can’t recover it using Time Machine

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, software-update, reboot

This morning I wanted to restart my MacBook, and while it was loading, all of a sudden it got shut down. I think that it was downloading updates and couldn't install those because there was not enough space. I tried reinstalling macOS but due to a memory shortage, this also didn’t work. When I try to use Time Machine it also didn't help. I have searched my issues on the internet multiple times already, but I don’t know what to do. I have tried CTRL + S option also but it also didn’t work.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking?  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What can I do to possibly get it to start up again? Or is he a goner?

Comment: You can try holding `Cmd+R` on reboot and recovering from Time Machine if you have a backup.

Comment: I tried but it cannot find any :(

Comment: Did MPB start up using Cmd-R?

Comment: What year is your MPB and is there an Apple Store near you?

Comment: If your time machine disk is built into or connected to your router (AirPort) then you will need to connect to your network via wifi/ethernet before you search for Time Machine. Your computer will not auto-connect to WiFi networks like it would normally when in recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Time Machine backup on an external drive, a Time Capsule or NAS? Is it possible to inspect the state of the Time Machine backup at Finder level connected to another Mac? You should be able to see the date of the last successful backup and possibly an 'in progress' file which would signify the last backup failed to complete. Try delete this file, it might be the cause. Assuming the TC backups are accessible through the Finder, I would choose the 'Reinstall MacOS' option and install via Apple's servers, then do a restore via the Migration Assistant.